# Group by data in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a set of points in the following format. For each Id1, there is a set of Id2's with their latitude and longitude. For each group of Id1 and Id2, I need the first record in the group
except for the last group, in which i need both the first and last records. Please see below the output.

Just wondering is there a way in pandas I can achieve this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
  Id1       Id2       Latitude        Longitude
  179       183       33.67           -83.24
  179       183       31.33           -83.11
  179       184       33.58           -83.34
  179       184       33.61           -83.14
  179       185       33.60           -83.54
  179       185       33.60           -83.54
  180       185       33.67           -83.64
  180       185       33.79           -83.74
  180       186       33.81           -83.84
  180       186       33.81           -83.84
```

Output:

```
  Id1       Id2       Latitude        Longitude
  179       183       33.67           -83.24
  179       184       33.58           -83.34
  179       185       33.60           -83.54
  179       185       33.60           -83.54
  179       186       33.79           -83.74
  179       186       33.81           -83.84
  180       185       33.67           -83.64
  180       186       33.81           -83.84
  180       186       33.81           -83.88
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'last group'? In what sense last?

Comment: If we order by Id1 and Id2, the last group would be 179,186 in my example

Comment: In each group are only 2 rows?

Comment: Yes, this works if we have one group.

Comment: @jezrael: Thank you. I have edited the question. .This works if we have one unique group in the dataframe. If we have more than one Id1 and Id2 combination, this does not work for all the groups.

Comment: In each group are only 2 rows?

Comment: Yes, there will be only 2 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is a bit less pandas-oriented but it uses `group-by` operations:

```
# Function to check if row values are equal to last_group values
def compare_to_groups(x, last_groups):
    return  any((x[['Id1','Id2']] == last_groups[i]).all(1).any() for i in range(len(last_groups)))

# Get the last groups
last_groups = df.groupby('Id1')['Id1','Id2'].last().values

# Apply to each group
df.groupby(['Id1','Id2']).apply(lambda x: x if compare_to_groups(x, last_groups) else x.head(1)).reset_index(drop=True)
```

It should yield:

```
   Id1  Id2  Latitude  Longitude
0  179  183     33.67     -83.24
1  179  184     33.58     -83.34
2  179  185     33.60     -83.54
3  179  185     33.60     -83.54
4  180  185     33.67     -83.64
5  180  186     33.81     -83.84
6  180  186     33.81     -83.84
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to retrieve the last two rows for each group. I have edited the Output now. So for Id1 = 179, the last group would be 185, hence i need the two rows corresponding to Id1 = 179 and Id2 = 185.

Answer (score 1):

You can first find last value of column `Id2`, then filter where are no last values by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
last_row = df['Id2'].iloc[-1]
print (last_row)
186

df1 = df[df.Id2 != last_row].drop_duplicates(['Id1','Id2'])
print (df1)
   Id1  Id2  Latitude  Longitude
0  179  183     33.67     -83.24
2  179  184     33.58     -83.34
4  179  185     33.60     -83.54
7  180  185     33.67     -83.64
```

Then filter values with last value in `Id2`:

```
df2 = df[df.Id2 == last_row]
print (df2)
    Id1  Id2  Latitude  Longitude
5   179  186     33.81     -83.84
6   179  186     33.81     -83.84
9   180  186     33.81     -83.84
10  180  186     33.81     -83.84
```

And last [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) together:

```
print (pd.concat([df1,df2]).reset_index(drop=True))
   Id1  Id2  Latitude  Longitude
0  179  183     33.67     -83.24
1  179  184     33.58     -83.34
2  179  185     33.60     -83.54
3  180  185     33.67     -83.64
4  179  186     33.81     -83.84
5  179  186     33.81     -83.84
6  180  186     33.81     -83.84
7  180  186     33.81     -83.84
```

If need only last group change condition:

```
lastId1 = df['Id1'].iloc[-1]
print (lastId1)
180
lastId2 = df['Id2'].iloc[-1]
print (lastId2)
186

mask = (df.Id1 == lastId1) & (df.Id2 == lastId2)
df1 = df[~mask].drop_duplicates(['Id1','Id2']).drop_duplicates(['Id1','Id2'])
print (df1)
   Id1  Id2  Latitude  Longitude
0  179  183     33.67     -83.24
2  179  184     33.58     -83.34
4  179  185     33.60     -83.54
5  179  186     33.81     -83.84
7  180  185     33.67     -83.64

df2 = df[mask]
print (df2)
    Id1  Id2  Latitude  Longitude
9   180  186     33.81     -83.84
10  180  186     33.81     -83.84

print (pd.concat([df1,df2]).reset_index(drop=True))
   Id1  Id2  Latitude  Longitude
0  179  183     33.67     -83.24
1  179  184     33.58     -83.34
2  179  185     33.60     -83.54
3  179  186     33.81     -83.84
4  180  185     33.67     -83.64
5  180  186     33.81     -83.84
6  180  186     33.81     -83.84
```